# Get total physical memory size over 2GB of computer from Java in 32-bit Windows

Tags: java

I'm trying to programatically retrieve the total physical memory available on a Windows XP, using Java 7. I'm using the [OperatingSystemMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html) to retrieve this value

```
((com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean()).getTotalPhysicalMemorySize()
```

However, this returns 2147483647 (2GB), while the Task Manager reports a total physical memory of 3669488 KB.

As far as I understand, a 32-bit OS will allow a maximum of 2GB RAM per process, so my guess is that this is somehow interfering with the OSMXBean methods. Is there another way to obtain the total physical memory size, that works correctly across platforms (ie 32 and 64 bits)?

Answer (score 0):

32bit Windows just can't allocate over 2GB to a process. Even when you have the full 4 GB RAM it theretically can allcoate, then you have 2GB of RAM vor OS usage only.

So there no way to retrive more then the 2GB RAM for your process on your 32bit Windows. To get more you have to 64bit.

For more information: [here](https://superuser.com/questions/253633/2gb-limit-on-32bit-operating-systems)

Comment: I understand the limitation of RAM to be allocated per process, but what I want to do is know how much memory is installed on the local computer, not actually use it from the Java process.